# Can you add a job to APScheduler after you've already started a BlockingScheduler instance?

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, apscheduler

After creating an instance of `sched = BlockingScheduler()`, I'm unable to import the sched object because, obviously, the thread is blocked from executing and nothing is returned to sched in the first place.

However, I want to dynamically add jobs to the scheduler after the instance is created. Do I have to use `BackgroundScheduler` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Creating the instance won't block. Starting the scheduler will. BlockingScheduler was intended to be used so that you instantiate the scheduler, add jobs to it and then leave it to running.

You can still schedule new jobs from other jobs, or non-scheduler threads if you have some running. You haven't told anything about the kind of application you're writing so I can't tell you which you should be using.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've gained insight. Based on your response, I think I need to use BackgroundScheduler because I'd like to add jobs after the scheduler has already started. Is that right?

Comment: Like I said, I don't know anything about your application so I don't know why you can't add them beforehand, or from scheduled jobs. There is no harm in using BackgroundScheduler instead, so long as you don't exit the main thread right after starting it.